# SQL multiple column ordering randomly

Tags: mysql

I want to order highlight by `rand()` without modifying the syntax. How to do ?

I've tried with `ORDER BY servers.highlight rand()` but still not working.

```
ORDER BY `servers`.`highlight` DESC, `servers`.`votes` DESC,`servers`.`online_players` DESC,`servers`.`status` DESC
```

Comment: Are there multiple rows in the output for each value from `highlight`?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to achieve this is to do the random ordering of `servers.highlight` in the original `JOIN`. Attempting to `ORDER BY RAND()` at the end will simply give random ordering to the entire output. Something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * FROM servers.highlight ORDER BY RAND()) h
JOIN servers.votes ON ...
```

I've created a small [demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1305d816de6e246aa356c71e6dd78852) to demonstrate.